# Tailwindcss margin not working inside docker but works perfectly outside container

Tags: css, docker, next.js, tailwind-css

Sample: https://play.tailwindcss.com/Xialm0nYXU (this works as expected in tailwind playground & when app is run directly on laptop but not within my containerized app. The margins mx are not working only inside containers.)

I have a HTML code that is similar to the above (but within a larger application). The margins between the `<p>` elements work fine while testing locally. But once I containerize my application it stops working. Oddly margin works at `mx-2` but nothing else work, padding is not working either. Margins for other elements work fine (even inside container), so it should be something about this shared snippet that stops working inside a container. I could not share the whole application code, so I understand you might not have full context to understand what else could be happening. But want to check if anyone knows what could possibly cause issue only when run inside container. I suspect something gets messed up in the containerization process. Appreciate any pointers here.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/


COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

ENV NODE_ENV production

CMD ["npm", "start" ]
```

tailwind.config.json:

```
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

module.exports = {
  purge: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'
  ],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        blueGray: colors.blueGray,
        emerald: colors.emerald,
        lime: colors.lime,
        trueGray: colors.trueGray,
        teal: colors.teal,
        cyan: colors.cyan,
        sky: colors.sky,
        warmGray: colors.warmGray,
        green: {
          25: '#f5fff8'
        }
      },
      fontSize: {
        'xxs': '.70rem'
      },
      overflow: ['hover', 'focus'],
      textOverflow: ['hover', 'focus']
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {
      display: ['hover', 'focus', 'group-hover'],
      opacity: ['disabled'],
      backgroundColor: ['active'],
      whitespace: ['hover', 'focus'],
      width: ['hover', 'focus'],
    },
  },
  plugins: [  
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
  ],
}
```

postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

Update: The problem turned out to be me dynamically generating tailwind class names through string concatenation. Exactly what the tailwind folks recommended not to do as PurgeCss cant recognize those classes at build time. Once i turned that into an annoyingly long conditional statement returning statically coded class names things started working fine. For information on this checkout tailwind doc - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#writing-purgeable-html

Comment: I assume it has something to do with your purge settings + the fact that your docker container has `NODE_ENV` set to production but i am currently unable to verify that.

Comment: I had similar suspicion and tried './**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}' and removed Prod node build. Neither worked.

Comment: Update: Once I comment out all the line within element "purge:" then the margins work as expected.
But commenting out purgecss doesnt sound like a proper solution. Anyone know whats wrong with my purge config.

Comment: So looks like this could be the reason. "it is important to avoid dynamically creating class strings in your templates with string concatenation, otherwise PurgeCSS won’t know to preserve those classes." In my app the css classes for the list is determined dynamically at runtime. So probably when post css is run it didn't find a need to preserve the mx classes and remove it. Exaplains when why margin class was not available while inspecting element in browser.

Comment: @broun You can add the solution to your problem as an answer to your own question. That clearly indicates the question already has an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be me dynamically generating tailwind class names through string concatenation. Exactly what the tailwind folks recommended not to do as PurgeCss cant recognize those classes at build time. Once I turned that into an annoyingly long conditional statement returning statically coded class names things started working fine. For information on this checkout tailwind doc - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#writing-purgeable-html